# Issue with ORDER By while trying to migrate from SQL Server 2012 to 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, database-migration

I'm trying to migrate from SQL Server 2012 to 2016 and have run the Microsoft Database Migration Assistant for the same. In the migration assistant, I'm just trying to cover Breaking changes. One of the breaking changes is showing as follows.

```
select 
Name1 as 'Name',
Age1 as 'Age' from Table 
order by 'Name'
```

The following explanation is coming for it.

> Constant expressions are allowed (and ignored) in the ORDER BY clause when the database compatibility mode is set to 80 or earlier. However, these expressions in the ORDER BY clause will cause the statement to fail when the database compatibility mode is set to 90 or later.

Here is an example of such problematic statements:

```
SELECT * FROM Production.Product
ORDER BY CASE WHEN  1=2 THEN 3 ELSE 2 END
```

However, after creating the same schema and running the same code in SQL Server 2016, the statement seems to be working fine. Am I missing out on anything?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select 
Name1 as Name,
Age1 as Age from Table 
order by Name
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But my question is more like whether there is any issue with what I have written. Because my the aliases I have given and the examples given by the DBA don't seem a bit alike....

Answer (score 0):

I think rather than evaluating the expressions if the migration assistant sees a hint of an order by clause it just give the warning. Messy I know but @Esperento57 's method is the only way to get it going.